# Cortana - OAuth 2 connected service

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

We have created an OAuth2 provider as an app service as given in below example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Step 2:

We need to configure this endpoints to Cortana connected service OAuth2 end points to get the access token from Cortana app

[Cortana Auth Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRktg.png)

Sample Code in the Auth provider authorize function is below:

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        var authentication = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            var isPersistent = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("isPersistent"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.Signin")))
            {
                authentication.SignIn(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent },
                    new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, Request.Form["username"]) }, "Application"));
            }
        }

       return View();
      //  Response.End();
    }
```

Authorize

```
 public ActionResult Authorize()
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode != 200)
        {
            return View("AuthorizeError");
        }


        var authentication = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var ticket = authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Application").Result;
        var identity = ticket != null ? ticket.Identity : null;
        if (identity == null)
        {
            authentication.Challenge("Application");
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

        var scopes = (Request.QueryString.Get("scope") ?? "").Split(' ');

        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.Grant")))
             {
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity.Claims, "Bearer", identity.NameClaimType, identity.RoleClaimType);
                foreach (var scope in scopes)
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", scope));
                }
                authentication.SignIn(identity);


            }
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.Login")))
            //{
            //    authentication.SignOut("Application");
            //    authentication.Challenge("Application");
            //    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            //}
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I want to change this code in a way that it could be able to send back data to Cortana channel. Please let know your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Are you using https://www.knowledge.store/? The image you added looks taken from there. If so here is the docs that explain how to auth your skill: https://help.knowledge.store/system_concepts/authentication/index.html?highlight=auth

Comment: Thanks. I went through this already. I would like to know how to return back to cortana from Auth provider. Would response.redirect work simply or do I need to user any other way to get the token from my Oauth2 provider?